# Autogenerate href link from text using Angular 4

Tags: json, angular

### TL;DR

How can I present a hyperlink to the browser from some text received in json?

### Scenario

i'm working in Angular 4 calling arrays from an object that's inside a json file, it's for a very basic blog. The thing is that in the json i'm consulting there's a field called "body" in which the body of a post is loaded, what i need to do is recognize every link in that text when it's loaded inside the div that's calling it.

the Json looks like this:

```
{"posts": [

{
  "id": 1,
  "date":"November 10th, 2017",
  "time":"3:50PM",
  "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
  Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque 
  penatibus 
  et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam 
  felis",
  "img": null
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "date":"November 10th, 2017",
    "time":"3:50PM",
    "body": "Loremsa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis",
    "img": null
  
  },

{
    "id": 3,
    "date":"November 10th, 2017",
    "time":"3:50PM",
    "body": "http://www.webesite.com  Lorem  elit. Aenean commodo ligula 
    eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur 
    ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis",
    "img": "https://scontent.fcnq1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/22491481_680661882130471_2500422036645997028_n.jpg?oh=2e5001e92d201e446e3120204869a434&oe=5A68A19D"
  }
]

}
```

And i'm calling it from a div using *ngFor like this

```
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-12 card-inf bg-inf-blue text-white mb-3 px-0" *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <div class="card-header-inf">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h6>Informatorio</h6>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right"><small>{{post.date}} - {{post.time}}
    </small></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body-inf bg-inf-blue pt-0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">{{post.body}}</div>
        <div class="col-12  mt-3 img-responsive" *ngIf = "post.img != null">
          <img src="{{post.img}}" alt="" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail ">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, at the start of the "body" field in the third array of the json there's a link in flat text, what i need is that link to be recognized as a link in the view.

Comment: Can you please provide your work so far and an example json so we can understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes! i'm sorry!, the code is already there.

Comment: OK So you want the card to hyperlink to links if they exist and allow the user to open it in the browser?

Comment: That's exaclty what i want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hyperlink-given-json) for you.
The approach here was to utilize innerHtml and pass the post.body to a function to build the formatted html.

### component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <div [innerHTML]="parseBody(post.body)">
  </div>
</div>
```

### component.ts

```
parseBody(body:string) {
  // TODO you will need to improve this regex.
  return body.replace(/(http.*?\s)/, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>")
}
```

Comment: Great! thank you for all your help! it works perfectly

Comment: small improvement regex: /(http.*?(\s|$)/
Thus it will take into account links which are at the end of the text.